# TTK Treeview: scale row with content

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Good evening.

I am trying to work with the ttk Treeview widget and want to append entries with more than one line to it. Unfortunately, if I try to do this more than once, the second entry will just cover the first, thus making the content basically unreadable, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkxFF.png).
Because every entry has a different number of lines, I cannot set the height of the rows in the Treeview to a specific value; instead, every single one has to be scaled independently, according to the number of lines.

The problem can be illustrated here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

decCols = ('colOne', 'colTwo')

decLog = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=decCols, show='headings')
decLog.heading('colOne', text='Column 1')
decLog.heading('colTwo', text='Column 2')
decLog.grid(row=0, column=0)

one = "Lorem"

mult = 'Ipsum \n Dolor \n'

data = (one, mult)

decLog.insert('', END, values=data)
decLog.insert('', END, values=data)

root.mainloop()
```

If anyone knew how to solve this problem, I would be grateful for a simple and effective answer.

Thanks in advance,
Jiscona

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: @JRiggles I am sorry, i thought this problem was reocurring and had a "one size fits all"-solution...I edited my question to have an example now.

Comment: one = "Lorem"

mult = 'Ipsum Dolor'

data = (one, mult)

decLog.insert('', END, values=data)
decLog.insert('', END, values=data)

Comment: I removed '\n' in line 15

Answer (score 0):

You can set the row height for *every* row in the `Treeview` using `ttk.Style`

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=24) 
# try setting row height to ~2x your font size
```

The caveats here are:

- You'll have to size your rows to fit two lines of text (or whatever is the greatest number of lines you expect to accommodate)
- Rows with fewer lines than that will be larger than necessary

---

If you'd like to eliminate the guesswork in sizing to fit your font, you can use tkinter's `Font` module to query your chosen font's actual height

```
from tkinter.font import Font

font = Font(family='Arial', size=20)  # use whatever font you like
line_height = font.metrics()['linespace']  # returns an integer
# set Treeview row height based on font size
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=line_height)
```

Unfortunately there's no easy way that I'm aware of to set `Treeview` row heights dynamically, but I hope this helps.